# How "to cook" is used in British slang?

Tags: vocabulary, british-english, slang

> stuck on silly ideas 'cause it's all you can cook

It's a quote from a British rap song. I understand that "cook" here means "do" or "think of", am I right?

The aspect which interests me the most here is: what group in the UK uses this word? What does it tell about me if I use this word? (For example about my age, my music taste etc.)

Please, provide two more examples of usage of this word.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this rap song is using language poetically and non-standardly.  So there aren't "more examples of 'cook' used in this sense."  Questions about lyrics are frequently unanswerable as lyricists bend or break all the "rules" to create songs.  Please enjoy songs and raps in English, but don't treat them as a source of grammar analysis.

Comment: **don't treat them as a source of grammar analysis** - absolutely this.

Comment: @JamesK If there aren't more examples, how come Weather Vane managed to write an answer and quote a dictionary? They didn't differenciate between "cook" and "cook up". Do you? Would you like to say that "cook up" is used like this, while "cook" isn't?

Comment: Well I think that answer is wrong, or at least unsupported.  I don't think it is clear that "cook" means "cook up"  I think it is more likely to be a metaphor created by the writer for this situation, not a development of the idiom "cook up".  Really the only way to know would be to talk to the artiste themselves - and that's not going to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its meaning is more specific than just "do" or "think of". The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cook-up) has

> **cook something up**
> <sup>informal</sup>
> to invent a story, plan, etc., usually dishonestly:
> *She cooked up some weird scheme that was going to earn her a fortune.*
> *I had to cook up an excuse about my car breaking down.*

In the song, the rapper has shortened it to just 'cook'.

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cook+up) has

> **cook up**
> Fabricate, concoct, as in *She's always cooking up some excuse.*

There's a similar difference between your "think of" and "think up".

**think of**: to remember something or someone.
**think up**: to invent something, to have an idea.

Comment: But there it is not cook up.

Comment: @Lambie, the rapper has shortened it to cook. That's what they do.

Comment: Hmm, I dunno, really.

Comment: The line is about cooking up ideas, which are silly.

Comment: Are rap questions really on-topic for ELU?

Comment: I do understand what you meant about dropping the up but it may not be the idea of cook up at all.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a matter of opinion what the rapper means, as is often the case in music and poetry too.